# How can I get rows with specific conditions in r

Tags: r, dplyr

Say that I have a `df`.

I want to get the `id` with two conditions at the same time:

1. the `id`'s `code` should contaions a capital `I`, regardless of the number that follows it. For example `I11`, `I31`...
2. the `id`'s `code` should contaions specific `code`: `E12`.

On the example below, the filtered `id` should be `id = 1` and `id = 2`. Because they all  contain `I` and `E12`.

Same `id` in the example means in the same group.

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), diag = c("main", "other", "main", 
"other", "main", "other", "main", "other", "main", "other", "main", 
"other", "main", "other", "main", "other", "main", "other", "main", 
"other", "main", "other"), code = c("I11", "E12", "I11", "Q34", 
"I31", "C33", "E12", "I34", "E12", "I45", "E12", "Z11", "E13", 
"Z12", "E14", "Z13", "I25", "E1", "I25", "E2", "I25", "E3")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -22L), groups = structure(list(
    id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), .rows = structure(list(1:6, 7:10, 11:16, 
        17:22), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE))

> df
# A tibble: 22 × 3
# Groups:   id [4]
      id diag  code 
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
 1     1 main  I11  
 2     1 other E12  
 3     1 main  I11  
 4     1 other Q34  
 5     1 main  I31  
 6     1 other C33  
 7     2 main  E12  
 8     2 other I34  
 9     2 main  E12  
10     2 other I45  
# … with 12 more rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```r
df |>
  group_by(id) |>
  filter(TRUE %in% str_detect(code, "I") & TRUE %in% (code == "E12")) |>
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 10 × 3
      id diag  code 
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
 1     1 main  I11  
 2     1 other E12  
 3     1 main  I11  
 4     1 other Q34  
 5     1 main  I31  
 6     1 other C33  
 7     2 main  E12  
 8     2 other I34  
 9     2 main  E12  
10     2 other I45
```

Or if you just want the groups add `distinct(id)` after the `filter(...)`:

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 1
     id
  <dbl>
1     1
2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, you want all records that are Ixx OR "E12"? Your 'at the same time' threw me off a little.
If this is what you mean this should get your results.
Using library(tidyverse):

```
df %>% filter(grepl("^I",code) | code == "E12")
```

meaning filter records where column code contains I OR records where code equals E12.

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests<sup>[1]</sup> that you're mostly interested in the `id` values that fulfil both of your conditions; in which case, you don't really need to work on a data frame, but only on vectors:

```
intersect(df$id[grepl("^I", df$code)], df$id[df$code=="E12"])
```

You create two string vectors of `df$id`s, one for each condition, then extract their shared terms (this also removes duplicates, so the output is `1 2`).

This requires nothing more than base R and I suspect is much more efficient than any table-based approach (especially if grouping or pivots are involved).

[1] and if you're not, you can still use the line above to index a table row-wise, e.g.

```
df[df$id %in% intersect(df$id[grepl("^I", df$code)], df$id[df$code=="E12"]), ]
```

This will return all the rows of `df` with an `id` of 1 or 2 (including, however, those rows that have a matching `id` but a different `code`, e.g. "Q34").